# php code skipping some html content

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

my php code works fine on local server but does not execute on web server 
some of the codes are working.
the code is given down and please tell me problem with the code.

```
<?php
include("/connect.php");
session_start();
$_SESSION['title']="Portfolio | Mactros Inc.";
include("header.php");
?>
    <div>
        <center>
            <font size=7 class="top">
                Portfolio<br />
            </font>
            <font style="color: #aeafb1;"><a href="index.php" style="color: #aeafb1;">Home</a> -> Portfolio</font>
        </center>       
    </div>
    <div style="height: 650px; margin-top: 10px;">
        <?php
            $sql = "select * from project";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        ?>    
        <div class="portfolio">
            <center>
                <img src="<?php echo $row["pic"]; ?>" class="port">
                <font size=5><?php echo $row["name"];?></font><br>
                <font><?php echo $row["type"];?></font>
            </center>
        </div>
       <?php }?>
    </div><?php    include("footer.php");?>
```

in this code gets executed other gets ignored

```
<?php
include("/connect.php");
session_start();
$_SESSION['title']="Portfolio | Mactros Inc.";
include("header.php");
?>  <div>
        <center>
            <font size=7 class="top">
                Portfolio<br />
            </font>
            <font style="color: #aeafb1;"><a href="index.php" style="color: #aeafb1;">Home</a> -> Portfolio</font>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
include("/connect.php");
```

This is an absolute path, I don't think your script is at the root of your filesystem, use a relative path instead, and don't disable errors.

Comment: other pages are working good

Answer (score 0):

Write this line of code at top of you script file to show errors which are occurring into script.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```